# How to wrap object being constructed with Proxy inside constructor?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class, es6-proxy

I understand that `Proxy` can be used to alter object-level behaviors, such as bracket notation get and set. All the examples I can find show constructing an object and then wrapping it with a `Proxy` call. Is there a way to define a class `Foo`, using ES6 class constructor notation, such that the returned object from the constructor is already wrapped in `Proxy`, rather than the caller of the constructor having to also call `Proxy` separately?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, there is, but you probably should avoid it. Rather have a factory function (that might be a static method) that produces proxy-wrapped instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, what you want to do, is in the constructor return a new proxy like this:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    return new Proxy(this, {
      // Proxy settings here
    })
  }
}
```

Here in this example, we create a new class, then call a few properties. The proxy will then just print out the properties that were called for simplicity.

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get: (target, key) => {
        console.log('I am the key: ' + key)
        return Reflect.get(target, key)
      }
    })
  }
}

let c = new MyClass
c.awesome
c.billy
c.superTroopers

if (c instanceof MyClass) {
  console.log('I am an instance of MyClass')
} else {
  console.log('I am not an instance of MyClass')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It looks like what I was originally looking for. As a follow-up: Does this work as expected with `instanceof`, or would further fiddling be necessary if that behavior is desired?

Comment: Yes it does. If you see my edits, you will see that it prints `I am an instance`.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know: no, but you can set the `prototype` afterwards. Something like this:

```
class Thing {

    constructor() {
        // ...
    }

}

Thing.prototype = new Proxy(Thing.prototype, {

    get(target, name) {
        // ...
    }

});
```